# Using Tkinter to disable entry with specified input

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, disable

I would like to use Tkinter to be able to disable one entry if 'no' is selected from a drop down menu.

```
from tkinter import *

def disableEntry(entry):
    entry.config(state='disable')

def allowEntry(entry):
    entry.config(state='normal')


def main():
    print("test")

root = Tk() #create a TK root window
root.title("Lunch and Learn")  #Title of the window

L1 = Label(root, text = "Label 1").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=(20,5))
L2 = Label(root, text = "Label 2").grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)

var = StringVar()

E1 = Entry(root,bd =3)
E1.grid(row=0, column=1)
D1 = OptionMenu(root,var,"yes","no")
D1.grid(row=1,column=1)

if var.get() == 'no':
    disableEntry(E1)
elif var.get() == 'yes':
    allowEntry(E1)

B2 = Button(text = "Submit", command=main).grid(row=4, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

the above code is a simple example of what i have tried. I have created two functions called 'disableEntry' and 'allowEntry' which should change the state of the entry box but they don't appear to do anything when i change the input of the drop down menu.

i dont know if i am approaching this the wrong way or if there is a standardized way to do this.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to check the state of the selection after it is changed. That can be achieved with adding a callback command to the OptionMenu widget.

You were checking the correct variable, but the point you were checking it at was before the screen window had even displayed.

```
from tkinter import Label, StringVar, OptionMenu, Entry, Tk, Button

# change the state of the Entry widget
def change_state(state='normal'):
    E1.config(state=state)

def main():
    print("test")

# callback function triggered by selecting from OptionMenu widget
def callback(*args):
    if var.get() == 'no':
        change_state(state='disable')
    elif var.get() == 'yes':
        change_state(state='normal')

root = Tk() #create a TK root window
root.title("Lunch and Learn")  #Title of the window

L1 = Label(root, text="Label 1").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=(20, 5))
L2 = Label(root, text="Label 2").grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)

var = StringVar()

E1 = Entry(root, bd=3)
E1.grid(row=0, column=1)
D1 = OptionMenu(root, var, "yes", "no", command=callback)
D1.grid(row=1, column=1)

B2 = Button(text = "Submit", command=main).grid(row=4, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```